# Two inline-block elements change places when the second is floated?

Tags: html, css

I have two inline block elements, `<h1>` and `<ul>` next to one another. When I float the second element, it takes the space of the first, i.e they switch places. Why is this? Why doesn't the second element place next to the `<h1>`? Here is the code:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #43116f;
  color: #e6e5df;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
}

.list li {
  border-color: #c8f69f;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.list li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(227, 192, 143);
  color: #43116f;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-family: "Leno", Serif;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>New Project</h1>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: because it's how float works ... you said it to be float left --> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

When you float elements, they float through other elements as far as they can. 
You can use **[clear](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)** to force floated elements to start below something:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #43116f;
  color: #e6e5df;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  float: left;
}
.clearer{
  clear: both;
}
.list li {
  border-color: #c8f69f;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.list li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(227, 192, 143);
  color: #43116f;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  font-family: "Leno", Serif;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>New Project</h1>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```